# Add images over photo

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to develop an app where the user can take a pic and then overlay some sprites over the photo.
Something like these apps "Make me |something|"

Here is an example [image]

But I really don't know what do I have to use (CoreGraphics, SpriteKit) to develop something like this. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done using `UIViews`

You can have a parent UIView

add a `UIImageView` in it . set it to custom photo image.
Now finally add a custom `UILabel` with text, another `UIImageView` or any other `UIView` to the parent view.

Then when you want to save just draw the parent `UIView` layer using core graphics(basically taking a screenshot) and save.

Comment: With iOS 7 the snapshot becomes even easier, just create an offscreen context and call `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`

Comment: And will I be able to allow the user to drag this image views that will be over the photo?

Comment: you can google on how to move UIView.. you will end up with touches began code or UIGestureRecognizer. both will work